# PostgreSQL - should I use EXCLUSIVE LOCK mode Logical Replication in Postgresql 11?

Tags: postgresql, citus

I am using the PostgreSQL 11 with Citus Extension community edition. I have 2 tables, each with 32 shards distributed among 2 nodes (Postgres servers with Citus Extension). Each shard from Table A has a group of Colocated shards (data dependent on each other).

I am trying to write a procedure that will replicate a shard and its co-located shards on a node to another node.

So I used the Publisher/Subscriber feature to set up the replication.
My question is while the replication is going on and a write(update/insert/delete) query comes, will the replication be affected in any way?

Should I use any kind of Lock in this case e.g. EXCLUSIVE LOCK MODE?

Answer (score 1):

Citus stores information on distributed table shards on several catalogue tables. Records in those tables should be updated to be able to use the new shard copies properly.

This is not a trivial task, and can potentially corrupt your existing Citus catalogue tables if not handled properly.

I suggest you consider using Citus Enterprise Edition that has this functionality already built and maintained by the developers.